# Push local commits on master branch to new remote branch

Tags: git, branch

I have local commits on the master branch, but (due to unforeseen external reasons) I now can't push my changes to master and instead need to push them to a new remote branch (that can be merged back to master later).

How do I (safely) do that?

Comment: Have you tried  `git push <REMOTENAME> <BRANCHNAME>` yet?

Comment: @AlexPan I haven't tried anything, because my experience with git is that you can monumentally screw things up very easily.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Push commits to another branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897717/push-commits-to-another-branch)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new branch:

```
git checkout -b myNewBranch
```

Push to repo:

```
git push
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way, without creating a new local branch as mentioned in the answer before, would be:
Imagine you are on branch `test` localy and want to push it to a new branch called `test-remote`

`$ git push origin test:test-remote`