# Working with remote repo git

Tags: git, github

I am very new to git. I am working with a remote repo.
I set up my my working environemnt like this:

```
git clone git@... /folder/
git branch -v
# origin git@... (fetch)
# origin git@ ... (push)
git branch someLocalBranch
```

What would I do if I want to pull changes from the `remote master` into my `local master`? And, how would I go on about `pushing` changes from `someLocalBranch` into a `remote branch`? That `remote branch` can either exist, or does not exist yet.

Comment: git push origin <branch name>

Comment: Learn git basics in just [15 min](https://try.github.io/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pull changes from remote master to your local master, checkout `master` on your local

```
git checkout master
```

and then pull the diff using -

```
git pull origin master
```

To push changes from `someLocalBranch`, commit all your changes while you are on the branch

```
git commit -a -m "message for commit"
```

and push them to remote

```
git push origin someLocalBranch
```

Now you can raise a Pull Request from this branch to any existing in the repository. Look [here](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request/) for more documentation on that.

To push changes from one branch to another, try using

```
git push origin someLocalBranch:someRemoteBranchABC
```

Do take a look at [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13897766/1746118) here.

Comment: how would I push from `someLocalBranch` to a branch called `someRemoteBranchABC`. A branch with a different name!

Answer (score 2):

your remote url is already set since you have cloned the remote repo. it's named "origin"

so to pull changes from the remote master you simply have to be on your local master branch :

```
git checkout master
```

and then :

```
git pull origin master
```

if you want to push your changes (after commiting them on your local branch)
be sure you're on the `someLocalBranch`:

```
git checkout someLocalBranch
```

then:

```
git push origin someLocalBranch
```

it will create the remote `someLocalBranch` if necessary, or simply push your change if it already exist