# git push origin doesn't create the remote branch

Tags: git, github

I cloned a repository to my local, made a branch, made the branch to track my local master. After changing, I committed my changes to my branch. and tried the following:

> git push origin my-local-branch

but when looking at my remote repo, there is no my-local-branch there and my changes have been already merged into (remote) master. Any idea why this might have happened.

I always do this at work. I wonder if there is some default settings at work that I don't have for myself.

UPDATE: This happened again. FYI, here's my chain of commands:

```
git checkout -b my-local
git branch --set-upstream-to master
...
git add -A
git commit
git push origin my-local
```

Again, code was merged directly into remote master and no branch was created in remote. Then, I tried the same thing but this time without **git branch --set-upstream-to master**. And this actually worked! Why is this happening. It doesn't sound like an expected behaviour.

Comment: "my changes have been already merged into (remote) master"! How is it possible if you not merge `your-branch` changes with `local-master` and push `remote-master`. Or, Create a pull request and merge to remote master? Can you attach your commands you've given ?

Comment: "git checkout -b my-local-branch" "git branch --set-upstream-to master" "git add -A" "git commit" "git push origin my-local-branch"

Comment: ok. I got your scenario now. You are doing `--set-upstream-to master` so, `local-branch` integrated with `remote master` (default `current-branch`) &  when you are pushing your changes it's updating `remote master`. I've attached an answer details.

Comment: I don't think so guys. I think you're reading the documentation wrong. Upstream is not equivalent to remote. Besides, this is what I see when I run set-upstream-to: "Branch my-local set up to track local branch master." It clearly says "local branch master" and not the remote master.

Answer (score 1):

You can try passing the -u options:

```
git push -u origin <branch>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
git branch --set-upstream-to master
```

This tells git that the upstream of your `my-local-branch` is your local `master` branch - I don't see why you would want to do that in the first place, as your goal seems to be that you have a branch called `my-local-branch` in your remote as well.

The simplest way is, in my opinion, to not use `--set-upstream-to` at all, but when you are doing your first push, do it like this:

```
git push -u origin my-local-branch
```

This creates a branch called `my-local-branch` on the remote as well, and sets it as the default upstream for you. Then you can just do `git push` without any arguments on subsequent pushes.

Answer (score 0):

```
git branch -vv
```

> -vv
>   --verbose When in list mode, show sha1 and commit subject line for each head, along with relationship to upstream branch (if any). If
>   given twice, print the name of the upstream branch, as well (see also
>   git remote show )

maybe your local branch is related to remote master.

Answer (score 0):

- When you are doing `set-upstream-to master`, your `local-branch` start tracking to `remote branch master`. So, After `pushing your local changes` it is updating `remote master branch` instead of `origin/your-local-branch`.

> --set-upstream-to=`<upstream>`
>   Set up 's tracking information so  is considered 's upstream branch. If no  is specified, then it defaults to the current branch.
>   [See More](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html)

- And when you didn't set `set-upstream-to master`, it `defaults to current local branch`. Now when you are pushing your changes it is creating `origin/your-local-branch` and updating with your changes.

If you want to see what tracking branches you have set up, you can use the `-vv` option.

```
$ git branch -vv
```

**Push to Non-default branch:**

- After setting `set-upstream-to master` (now default tracking branch is remote master), if you want to push `other remote branch`, need to push with `<source-branch>:<dest-branch>`.

  ```
  $ git push origin <local-branch>:<remote-branch>

  # if remote branch doesn't exit, do force push
  $ git push -f origin <local-branch>:<remote-branch>   # create a new branch and push to it
  ```

  [See More](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13897766/4133798)

Comment: No it doesn't. What you say is "When you are doing set-upstream-to master, your local-branch start tracking to remote branch master" but documentation doesn't say that. upstream is not equivalent to remote. Besides, when I run my set-upstream-to in my local repo what I get is this message: "Branch my-local set up to track local branch master." Git is clearly saying my branch is set to track local master and not remote master.

Comment: Yes. Your `local branch` tracking `local master` and your `local-master` tracking `remote-master`. So, when pushing, it is finding remote default-branch (`remote master`).