# Push to another branch with git

Tags: git

I done a clone of a projet via ssh

```
git clone ssh ssh://git@10.7.5.11:IMER/ropolo.git
```

`master` branch is protected so I can't push my changed.

there is another branch `dev_ropolo`.

Do I need to bring this branch locally.
What is needed to do to be able to push my change to this branch?

**Edit:**

```
$ git fetch
* [new branch]      ropolo -> origin/ropolo

$ git branch
* master
```

Comment: If you cloned the repository, you already should have that branch locally available. Just create a local branch from it using `git checkout -b dev_ropolo origin/dev_ropolo` and work on that one instead of master.

Comment: Do this: `git push <remote> <source branch>:<dev_ropolo>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Push commits to another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897717/push-commits-to-another-branch)

Answer (score 14):

Use fetch command in the local repo

```
$ git fetch
```

check that your branch has come to your local using

```
$ git branch
```

now change your branch using checkout

```
$ git checkout -b branch_name
```

do some changes then

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "message"
$ git push origin remote_branch_name
```

Answer (score 14):

```sh
git push <remote> <branch with new changes>:<branch you are pushing to>
```

Eg : git push origin branch1:branch2

Comment: Credit where it's due: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13897766/183120

Answer (score 5):

You said you cloned locally the repository, you can then access the branch `dev_ropolo` via:

```
git checkout dev_ropolo
```

you now have selected `dev_ropolo` as the current branch: do your local changes, add and commit, and then push them using:

```
git push origin dev_ropolo
```

(assuming that the remote is set to `origin`)

Comment: it's the same, you should be able to switch branch. if you still didn't commit your code, use `git stash`, switch to branch dev_ropolo and then `git stash pop`. then add, commit and push. but this is a broader scope respect to the original question

Comment: i don't see the change i done in master when i check dev_repolo

Comment: `dev_repolo` is a separate branch. to see the changes you did in master, you should merge it into `dev_repolo`. but really this is another problem, try to solve them one by one.

Answer (score -1):

to change the branch run:

```sh
$ git checkout -b branch_name
```

to push code to branch run:

```sh
$ git push origin remote_branch_name
```

Comment: If you change the branch it's no longer another branch...?