# How to move branch of one repository to the other branch of different repository

Tags: git

I've a repository called `communication_app` a branch called `teleApp` and other repository is `communication_app_patient` of branch called `patient_interface`

I want to push the code of `communication_app` changes in to `communication_app_patient`

how to migrate these changes?

Comment: `git push https://github.com/the_other_repo communication_app:communication_app_patient`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Push commits to another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897717/push-commits-to-another-branch)

Comment: i've two repo's , one of repo `communication_app` which i'm working and i want to push those changes  to `communication_app_patient`  repo

Answer (score -1):

First clone your initial repository to a new location (for example, ~/saveMe/initialRepo).

```
mkdir -p ~/saveMe/initialRepo
cd ~/saveMe/initialRepo
git clone <initial repository URL>
```

2. Checkout to the new implementation branch by creating a new local branch. (for example, go-implementation)
   `git checkout -b go-implementation origin/go-implementation`
3. Create the new repository on Git.
4. Clone the new repository to a new location. (for example, ~/saveMe/newRepo)

```
mkdir -p ~/saveMe/newRepository`
cd ~/saveMe/newRepo
git clone <new repository URL>`
```

5. Create a new remote inside the new repository (super-awesome-project) for the initial repository (awesome-project)
   `git remote add initial-repo <path-to-cloned-initial-repository>`
6. Pull all the files and directories from initial repository (awesome-project) go-implementation branch to the master branch of the new repository (super-awesome-project) with preserving history.
   `git pull initial-repo go-implementation --allow-unrelated-histories`
7. Remove the remote added for the initial repository (awesome-project) inside the new repository (super-awesome-project).
   `git remote rm initial-repo`
8. Add all changes and push to git.

```
git add .
git push origin
```

From the following article,
https://kasunsiyambalapitiya.medium.com/move-git-branch-from-one-repository-to-another-with-preserving-history-81ed64de3a02